# IllegalArgumentException on creation of TimeTicks object in SNMP4J

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

Using SNMP4J, I want to set the time in a switch using the switch vendor's proprietary OID for the current time.  Performing a MIB walk on the switch (as well as sniffing the SNMP traffic while setting the time with the switch's web interface) revealed the type of the parameter to be timeticks-value(3).  I thought this meant i should use the TimeTicks variable type in SNMP4J.  My problem is I simply cannot assign a TimeTicks object a value once created.

One of the TimeTicks constructors takes in a long argument;  this constructor is not documented(!) and throws an exception because the argument is not an UnsignedInteger32 type.  There is also a fromMilliseconds(long) method, which does the exact same thing:  an IllegalArgumentException is thrown because the argument is not an UnsignedInteger32 type.

My question is, is it possible to set a TimeTicks value with SNMP4J?

Comment: setting value via String also produces same IllegalArgumentException for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was a type problem, but it turned out that my problem was caused by using a long value that was out of unsigned int range; it works with values greater than 0 and below 4294967296.